# HTML buttons not appearing/elements stacked on each others

Tags: html, css

I followed a tutorial for a form(to make it look more professional) and I've followed each and every step carefully(I f#cked up something tho, I can't find it) and now all of my "fields" are stacked on each other. I have a php page that I make a form on and then if all the info is filled in and the user presses the "submit" button then it should send it to my and their email. It worked but when I started to follow this tutorial/guide the button disappeared, when I tried to find it on the page I couldn't see it/click it or anything. With some tricks I could see the outline of the button but not the actual button(there is a function in opera and I think many other browsers that while browsing through the elements on the page if you click on one of them in the source it highlights it on the page). The following is the source code, the only thing I want is the button to appear under the text fields and the text fields not to be stacked on top of each other, I'll only be including the html and not the php code for the smtp.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Enroll</title>
<link rel="icon" href="mail.png">
</head>
<style>

body{
background-color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
justify-content:space-around;
align-items:center;
flex-direction:column;
height:100%;;
}

.form{
overflow:hidden;
width:75%;
position:absolute;
left:10%;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
height:50px;
}

.form label{
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
pointer-events: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
transition: 0.3 ease;
}

.form label::after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    buttom:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
    transform translateX(-100%);
}

.button{
width:400px;
height:30px;
background-color:blue;
}

.form input{
width:100%;
height:100%;
color: #595f6e;
padding-top: 20px;
border: none;
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.content-name {
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
left:0px;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
}

.form input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
 transform: translateY(-150%);
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #5fa8d3;
}

.form input:focus{
    
}
</style>

<body>
<div align="center"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form class="form" action="" method="post">
    
    <input type="text" name="email" required />
    <label for="email" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name">Email</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    
    <input type="text" name="first_name" required />
    <label for="first_name" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name">First Name</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    
    
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <label for="last_name" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name">Last Name</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    
    
    <br>
          <input style="color:blue;" onClick="return empty()" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></br>
    </form>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see at least 2 typos: `buttom:0px;` and `transform translateX(-100%);`. And the `.button` class is never referenced.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

They are all stacking because you use `position:absolute` on `<label>` without proper parent reference on where they should be positioned. Try wrapping them with `<div>` like the example below, and add `position:relative` to that `div`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Enroll</title>
<link rel="icon" href="mail.png">
</head>
<style>

body{
background-color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
justify-content:space-around;
align-items:center;
flex-direction:column;
height:100%;;
}

.form{
overflow:hidden;
width:75%;
position:absolute;
left:10%;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
height:50px;
display: flex;
}
.form .field {
position: relative;
}

.form label{
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
pointer-events: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
transition: 0.3 ease;
}

.form label::after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    buttom:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
    transform translateX(-100%);
}

.button{
width:400px;
height:30px;
background-color:blue;
}

.form input{
width:100%;
height:100%;
color: #595f6e;
padding-top: 20px;
border: none;
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.content-name {
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
left:0px;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
}

.form input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
 transform: translateY(-150%);
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #5fa8d3;
}

.form input:focus{
    
}
</style>

<body>
<div align="center"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form class="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="email" required />
        <label for="email" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name">Email</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" required />
        <label for="first_name" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name">First Name</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
        <label for="last_name" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name">Last Name</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    
    <br>
          <input style="color:blue;" onClick="return empty()" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></br>
    </form>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```